# how to see two class result in java

Tags: java

Hi i am beginner in JAVA i have created two classes in one folder but if i am run these classes. only one class result show but second class result i can't see. How to print both classes.

Here is my Code:-

```
package faham;

public class StudentRoom {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    static String college = "ITS";

    static void change(){
        college = "BBITS";
    }

    StudentRoom(int r, String n){
        rollno = r;
        name = n;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(rollno + " " + name + " " + college);
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ){
        StudentRoom.change();
        StudentRoom s1 = new StudentRoom (111, "Mohd Javed");
        StudentRoom s2 = new StudentRoom (333, "Bashkar");
        StudentRoom s3 = new StudentRoom (222, "Faham Javed");

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        s3.display();
    }

    static class Calculate{
        static int cube(int x){
            return x*x*x;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            int result=Calculate.cube(5);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: but i can't see second class result i am put it outside

Comment: how do you call those classes?

Answer (score 1):

Create two different `.java` files for those two `public` classes, compile them seperately, run them separately. Before doing this, read more about the structure of a java program.

```
//StudentRoom.java
public class StudentRoom {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    static String college = "ITS";

    static void change(){
        college = "BBITS";
    }

    StudentRoom(int r, String n){
        rollno = r;
        name = n;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(rollno + " " + name + " " + college);
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ){
        StudentRoom.change();
        StudentRoom s1 = new StudentRoom (111, "Mohd Javed");
        StudentRoom s2 = new StudentRoom (333, "Bashkar");
        StudentRoom s3 = new StudentRoom (222, "Faham Javed");

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        s3.display();

        Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
        int cubeResult = calculate.cube(5);
        System.out.println("Cubed result" + cubeResult);
    }



}



//Calculate.java
public class Calculate{
        static int cube(int x){
            return x*x*x;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            int result=Calculate.cube(5);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using static class inside for learning basics of java. In your case it would be better to create Calculate as a separate class(see example below). You can then create object inside main and use cube() method.

```
package faham;

public class StudentRoom {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    static String college = "ITS";

    static void change(){
        college = "BBITS";
    }

    StudentRoom(int r, String n){
        rollno = r;
        name = n;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(rollno + " " + name + " " + college);
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ){
        StudentRoom.change();
        StudentRoom s1 = new StudentRoom (111, "Mohd Javed");
        StudentRoom s2 = new StudentRoom (333, "Bashkar");
        StudentRoom s3 = new StudentRoom (222, "Faham Javed");

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        s3.display();

        Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
        int cubeResult = calculate.cube(5);
        System.out.println("Cubed result" + cubeResult);
    }



}

class Calculate{
    static int cube(int x){
        return x*x*x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have classes as many as you wish
but if you want to treat classes as an application then you can have 1 main class

a main class is a class have`static main(String args)`

so, you need to keep 1 main() only, at the public class,
in your case its StudentRoom and call both classes on that main()

so your main should look like this

```
public static void main(String args[] ){
        StudentRoom.change();
        StudentRoom s1 = new StudentRoom (111, "Mohd Javed");
        :
        :
        :

        s1.display();
        :
        :
        :

//then 
        Calculate calc= new Calculate();
        int result=Calculate.cube(5);
            System.out.println(result);
    }
```

and the main at Calculate is not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can call method of any class by using a class which have a main method so there is no need to have main method in your class calculate.The only thing you have to do is to create an object of your class calculate and call the method.so the change will be

Just add this in your student class and remove the main method from your calculate class.

```
 public static void main(String args[] ){
        StudentRoom.change();
        StudentRoom s1 = new StudentRoom (111, "Mohd Javed");
        StudentRoom s2 = new StudentRoom (333, "Bashkar");
        StudentRoom s3 = new StudentRoom (222, "Faham Javed");

       Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
        int cubeResult = calculate.cube(5);


        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        s3.display();
System.out.println("Cubed result" + cubeResult);
```